# how to add category by UpgradeData in magento2

Tags: magento2

if I want add a new Category in magento2 by UpgradeData.php,how could i do.only need to add a new record in table catalog_category_entity?but I didn't found the Category name in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` and `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository` into your UpgradeData class:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }
```

Create a new category instance and set the required data:

```
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $category->setData('name', 'CATEGORY_NAME');
    [...] // set other category data here
```

Save the new category:

```
    $this->categoryRepository->save($category)
```